# What happens if I type > / on linux

Tags: linux, bash, file

When I type > file.extension I know that the file is replaced by a empty file.

What if then I type > / ?  My / partition will be erased and I'll lost everything in it?

I'm curious and wondering if someone already tried this.

Comment: The system will most probably reply with `/: Is a directory.`

Comment: @JID I'm pretty aware of that haha. Once I accidentally did this :( luckily it was a test machine

Comment: Is this a kindergarten?! If this should be of interest for you then you should either read the bash manual or if you are not able to do that then, try: `mkdir test; echo > test`. This is not a valid question on SO. SO is not funny!

Comment: I hope that everybody was getting my joke! It is indeed funny sometimes! :D

Answer (score 2):

You cannot redirect to a directory